# On injectivity of $F_N$

Tags: number-theory, functions

I am interested in the following problem:

> Let $F_N:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the function that maps a natural number $a$ to the least natural number more than or equal to $a$ for which there exists a sequence of natural numbers $a=x_1 <x_2<\ldots < x_m=F_N(a)$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that$$\prod_{i=1}^m x_i$$is a perfect $N^{th}$ power. For what values of $N$ is $F_N$ a injective function?

I have shown that $F_N$ is injective for $N=1,2$ however, I have no idea how do we decide if $F_N$ is injective for $N\geq 3$.

> Here's an example:
> $F_2(2)=6$ because $6$ is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $2$ for which there is a sequence of $x_i$ between $2$ and $6$ for which their product is a perfect square as $2\times 3\times 6$ is a perfect square.

**Progress.** So we know $F_1,F_2$ are injective and as noted out by @Ravi Fernando, $F_3$ is not injective as $F_3(6)=F_3(12)=18$.

Any help will highly be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should add Bounty ? This is really hard problem deserves more recognition :)

Comment: @Shubhangi I made a Bounty of 100 reputation points. :)

Comment: wait, I just realised you wrote my name .. Thanks for that :) , but was this a generalisation of the putnam problem , as far as I remember , my mentor gave the simple problem , right ?

Comment: @Shubhangi See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h566363p3315664

Comment: why "a function" rather than "the function"?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yeah, that's a mistake. I meant "the function"

Comment: I see no reason that any $F_N$ should be injective when $N > 2$.  At least $F_3$ isn't:  $F_3(6) = F_3(12) = 18$, using the cubes $6 \cdot 16 \cdot 18$ and $12 \cdot 18$.

Comment: Possible source of counterexamples in general:  if $N > 2$, $p$ is prime and $k$ is not divisible by $p$, then $F_N(k \cdot p^{N-1} - 2p)$ and $F_N(k \cdot p^{N-1} - p)$ are both at least $k \cdot p^{N-1}$.  It might (or might not) be possible to make them equal by choosing $k$ and $p$ appropriately.

Comment: @RaviFernando I see but do you have an explicit proof that for all $N>2, F_N$ is non-injective? BTW great observations!!

Comment: @Anand No, I haven't proved anything beyond $N = 3$.